# Fetch specific data using wildcards in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

i want to fetch data from database using LIKE or CONTAIN or any possible method where a string is entered with wildcard and the string is nearly same to any of the existing record it would fetch that record. E.g let's say a user entered "Ameri* Soci* of Chur* " and the presses enter this would fetch the record "American Society of Churches" and nothing else.

I am using contains but that is bringing me all the other records containing similar keywords.
 here is what i am doing. Thank you in advance.

```
 SELECT name From Mytable where contains (name, '"Ameri*" OR "Soci*" OR "Of Churc*"')
```

Comment: I think you should build a query looking something like this: `SELECT name FROM yourTable WHERE name LIKE 'Ameri*' OR name LIKE 'Soci*' OR name LIKE 'Churc*'` ... separate the keywords rather than insisting on using them together.

Comment: i do not want to split the string but treat it as a single string because in my front end user can input more than one topic and they are already being split by a function. Thank you for the reply though..

Answer (score 1):

The contains function does what it is supposed to be doing. ;)
Look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx , at example D.

It will find all records starting with either of your prefixes.
To find only the "American Society of Churches" you could use

```
... like 'Ameri% Soci% of Churc%'
```

Contains seems much more powerfull with all its possiblities, the question is what is it that you want to achieve.

Comment: thank you for the reply, although this is also a good method other than using CONTAINS ... and it also fetches all similar records only unlike Contains.. but i was looking for something that could bring specific data. I am looking into it. Thank you for the reply again  a almost perfect answer...

Comment: What do you mean by "specific data"?

Comment: i meant the particular data as the result could be the particular AMERICAN SOCIETY OF CHURCHES